# solaris sparc 9/10 libstdc++ compatibilty issue (64 bit)

Tags: solaris, sparc, libstdc++

I have gcc 3.4.6 installed on sparc9 and sparc10 systems. I am having incompatibility issues when I try to use shared object(built on sparc9) on sparc10. I am not seeing any issue if I use same shared object on sparc9 system. Snippet from makefile:-

```
LIB=-L/usr/lib/sparcv9 -L/usr/local/lib/sparcv9 -L/lib/sparcv9
gcc -m64 -shared -fPIC -o myapi.so.1 myapi.o $(LIB) -lc -lstdc++ -luuid
```

Now following in sparc10:-

```
ldd -d /home/myapi.so
libstdc++.so.6 =>        /usr/local/lib/sparcv9/libstdc++.so.6
symbol not found: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekoffExSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode                (./myapi.so)
```

I have skipped other dependencies in above output which appear normal.

Then, I ran "nm" against libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/local/lib/sparcv9 for above unreferenced symbol and came with following conclusion:-

```
V9---> _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekoffExSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode
V10--->_ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekoffElSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode
```

If you look carefully, you can see a difference in mangled-name symbol in sparc9 and sparc10... "ExSt12" v/s "ElSt12".

Similarly, if I build myapi.so on sparc10, it fails on sparc9 because of symbol mismatch in V9 and V10.

Can someone please point me to any helpful hints as to if I am missing something? Or do I need to install any package on V9. I am assuming that shared object built on V9 should work on V10.

I would like to add that there is a size of libstdc++.so.6 on V9 is different from V10. V9 has SMCgcc and V10 has both SUNWgccruntime and SMCgcc.

Answer (score 1):

Those symbols demangle as:

```
std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::seekoff(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir, std::_Ios_Openmode)
```

and

```
std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::seekoff(long, std::_Ios_Seekdir, std::_Ios_Openmode)
```

Notice that one uses `long` and the other uses `long long`

I suspect that means one was built with 64-bit file offsets (aka large file support) and the other wasn't.  That means the two versions of GCC have been built differently (by sunfreeware.com or whoever provided them) and are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using incompatible versions of the GNU C++ compiler & standard library on the two OS'es.  Unfortunately, there is no standard ABI for C++ and many compilers change symbol mangling conventions incompatibly between major releases (such as Sun C++ compiler 4.x vs. 5.x, or g++ 2.x vs. 3.x vs. 4.x).

The /usr/local/lib path implies you're using the libraries from the SMCgcc packages downloaded from the [sunfreeware.com](http://sunfreeware.com/) site - make sure you have matching versions on the Solaris 9 and 10 machines.   (There is no "sparc 10", so you must mean Solaris 10.)

Comment: @alanc..thanks for your help on this issue. gcc/g++ versions are 3.4.6 on both machines. However underlying "as" version of gcc is different on both machines. I am unable to find 64 bit SUNWgccruntime package for solaris9 (which is default package in solaris 10). In this scenario, should I check version of SMCgcc on solaris 10 and install same version on solaris 9? Is this recommended approach or should it be other way around?

Comment: SUNWgccruntime is the Solaris bundled gcc runtime, which was first added in Solaris 10 - it was never made for Solaris 9.